# jwplayer is looking for the flash player in my document root even when an alternate URL is supplied

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer7

I am using following variables to setup my jwplayer:

```
jwplayer("my-video").setup({
    file: "rtmp://<rtmp_distribution_url>/cfx/st/"+videoFile,
    width: "960",
    height: "540",
    autostart: true,
    mute: true,
    repeat: true,
     modes: [
    { type: "flash", src: "https://<my_cdn_url>/jwplayer.flash.swf"}, { type: "html5" }
     ]
});
```

The problem is that the flash player is not loading from my cdn. I have to place the jwplayer.flash.swf in my website's document root which is where it is looking for the player. If I remove the file from document root, I get an error that flash plugin cannot be loaded.

How do I load this file from the CDN? Is there any syntax error in the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

*modes* is now deprecated. My new config file compatible with jwplayer 7 looks like this:

```
 jwplayer("my-video").setup({
    playlist: [{
    sources: [{ 
        file: "<rtmp_server_url>/cfx/st/"+videoFile
    },{
        file: "<cdn_server_url>/"+videoFile
    }]
}],
    width: "100%",
    aspectratio: "16:9",
    autostart: true,
    mute: true,
    repeat: true,
    primary: "flash",
    flashplayer: "<cdn_server_url>/jwplayer.flash.swf",
    skin: {name: "five", url: "<cdn_server_url>/skins/five.css"}
});
```